# Spring Ldap ODM how to map attribute

Tags: java, spring-ldap

I'm creating a directory with spring boot, and I add the library Spring Ldap.

I created my odm of User and it works, but I don't know how to map attribute from another entry.

- My users are in `ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com`
- The user belongs to an unit in `ou=units,dc=mycompany,dc=com`
- The user have 0 or 1 manager in `ou=people,dc=mycompany.' same as users
- The user have 0 or more subsidiaries no attribute for that, I have to find it with the help of manager attribute.

Here my code:

```
@Entry( objectClasses = { "person", "top" }, base = "ou=People" )
public final class User{
    @Id private Name dn;
    private String fullname;
    private String mail;
    etc...
}
```

I would like to add `private User manager` and `private String unit` and `private List<User> subsidiaries` but I dont know how to map/link to another Entry.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for relations in Spring LDAP ODM. I'm not sure it would be quite worth the effort (since LDAP is not really a relational database anyway), but it could possibly be something we could take a shot at if the demand for it is high.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue, I've used a transient attribute in my User class :

```
@Attribute(name = "manager", syntax = "1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12")  
private Name managerName;

@Transient
private User manager;
```

Of course, you have to deal with the manager attribute yourself. Add the following code in your UserService class :

```
public User findUser(String uid) {
    User user = getRepo().findByUid(uid);
    if(null != user.getManagerName()) {
        User manager = getRepo().findOne(user.getManagerName());
        user.setManager(manager);
    } 
    return user;
}
```

You have to write something similar when saving your user object, in order to fill the managerName attribute with its new value if required.